# Serial port monitor for Arduino in Eclipse (on Linux x64)

Tags: arduino, serial, linux, monitor, eclipse

I like to program my Arduino using Eclipse. However, I still need the Arduino IDE to use the Serial port monitor.

This is very inconvenient and breaks my work flow

I tried to use RXTX but this would cause Eclipse to crash. I also tried to use a workaround using a SSH-Server but I didn't succeed.

Has anyone managed to monitor an Arduinos output from within Eclipse on a Linux x64 machine (I use Debian Testing), who could give some detailed instructions?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

All the "serial monitor" is, is a very basic terminal emulator.

You can install and use any serial terminal emulator in Linux that takes your fancy.

You should then be able to configure Eclipse to run that terminal emulator for you when you need it.

Comment: I see. Have you got any suggestions which serial terminals are good?
Thank you!

Comment: That depends how you define good. I use minicom a lot. The serial emulation is good but the program is not very useable as it is 100% terminal based. Have a look through the software manager.

Comment: gtkterm looks pretty basic (still has more than the "serial monitor" of the Arduino "IDE") and simple to use.